# Conditional KeyPress based on overall TextBox value

Tags: vb.net, textbox, event-handling, keypress

I have a `DataGridView` with a `TextBox` cell. I want to control what characters are entered into this cell, preferably on-entry rather than a post-entry validation. Currently, I keep it pretty simple; the textbox can only accept alpha-characters (either case), backspace, period and asterisk :

```
Private Sub dgv_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgv.EditingControlShowing
    If dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = myColumn.Index And Not e.Control Is Nothing Then
        Dim tb As TextBox = CType(e.Control, TextBox)
        With tb
            .CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper
            .MaxLength = 10
            AddHandler .KeyPress, AddressOf controlKeyPress
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub controlKeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim charEnum As Integer = CUInt(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar))
    Select Case charEnum
        Case 8, 42, 46, 65 To 90, 97 To 122
            ' Permit the keying of backspace (8), asterisk (42), period (46), upper-case alpha (65-90) and lower-case alpha (97-122)
        Case Else
            ' Suppress all other characters
            e.KeyChar = ""
    End Select
End Sub
```

Question : Is it possible to expand this to limit specific characters based on specific conditions for the overall value?

So, for example - is it possible to :

1. Permit the asterisk character (ASCII 42) but *only* if it is the *first* character (i.e. user can enter "*" but cannot enter "ABCD*")
2. Permit the period character (ASCII 46) but *only* if it is *not* the first character (i.e. user can enter "ABCD." but cannot enter ".ABCD")
3. Suppress *any* character if the first character is an asterisk (i.e. if user enters "*" then all subsequent characters are suppressed, apart from backspace, to allow them to delete it again)

Obviously the problem is that I can't access the rest of the `TextBox` value inside the `KeyPress` handler, to see where the pressed key is located and how that effects the overall value. The other problem is that the user could be replacing the whole of the current value in the `TextBox` (by selecting all of the existing text and replacing it with a keystroke), therefore the "current" value might be 6 characters long, but the `KeyPress` isn't necessarily appending character #7, it may be character #1 with the entire existing value being replaced.

Just trying to figure out which event I should be handling to perform this kind of conditional `KeyPress` control (I know I could just retrospectively correct the value in the `.CellValueChanged` event but it would be a lot cleaner if I could apply it up front, if at all possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For #1 and #2, you need `DirectCast(Sender, TextBox).SelectionStart`. For #3, you can use either `.Text.Substring()` or `.Text.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Aw, that's perfect, thank you so much @41686d6564standsw.Palestine really appreciated! Will post my updated code as the answer shortly

Comment: Question for @41686d6564standsw.Palestine : I've just discovered the same `.KeyPress` handler is being applied to other text boxes in a _different_ column (i.e. should not pass the  `dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = myColumn.Index` condition) Any ideas how/why that could be happening and how I can prevent it? I'm guessing I need to use a `RemoveHandler` somewhere but given I can't trap how the handler is being applied in the first place, I'm not sure where it should go? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per suggestion from @41686d6564standsw.Palestine here is the updated `KeyPress` handler to achieve the behaviour outlined in the question :

```
Private Sub controlKeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    Dim charEnum As Integer = CUInt(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar))
    Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Select Case charEnum
        Case 8
            ' Always permit the keying of backspace (no suppression)

        Case 42
            ' Permit the keying of asterisk (42) but only if it is the first character (otherwise, suppress the key press)
            If Not tb.SelectionStart = 0 Then e.KeyChar = ""

        Case 46
            ' Permit the keying of period (46) but only if it is not the first character and the first character is not an asterisk (otherwise, suppress the key press)
            If tb.SelectionStart = 0 OrElse tb.Text.FirstOrDefault = "*" Then e.KeyChar = ""

        Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122
            ' Permit the keying of upper-case alpha (65-90) and lower-case alpha (97-122) as long as the first character is not an asterisk (otherwise, suppress the key press)
            If tb.Text.FirstOrDefault = "*" Then e.KeyChar = ""

        Case Else
            ' All other characters, suppress the key press (set the KeyChar to nothing)
            e.KeyChar = ""
    End Select
End Sub
```